# How to return an array of JSON objects rather the a collection of rows using JOOQ & PostgreSQL

Tags: json, postgresql, jooq

Having read [this post](https://blog.jooq.org/stop-mapping-stuff-in-your-middleware-use-sqls-xml-or-json-operators-instead/) suggesting that it's sometimes a good trade-off to use JSON operators to return JSON directly from the database; I'm exploring this idea using PostgreSQL and JOOQ.

I'm able to write SQL queries returning a JSON array of JSON objects rather than rows using the following pattern:

```sql
select jsonb_pretty(array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(r)))::jsonb)
from (
  select [subquery]
) as r;
```

However, I failed to translate this pattern in JOOQ.

Any help regarding how to translate a collection of rows (fields being of "usual" SQL type or already mapped as json(b)) using JOOQ would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### SQL Server `FOR JSON` semantics

That's precisely what the SQL Server [`FOR JSON`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/select-statement/for-clause/) clause does, which jOOQ supports and which it can emulate for you on other dialects as well:

```java
ctx.select(T.A, T.B)
   .from(T)
   .forJSON().path()
   .fetch();
```

#### PostgreSQL native functionality

If you prefer using native functions directly, you will have to do with [plain SQL templating](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/) for now, as some of these functions aren't yet supported by jOOQ, including:

- `JSONB_PRETTY` (no plans of supporting it yet)
- `ARRAY_TO_JSON` (https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/12841)
- `ROW_TO_JSON` (https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/10685)

It seems quite simple to write a utility that does precisely this:

```java
public static ResultQuery<Record1<JSONB>> json(Select<?> subquery) {
    return ctx
        .select(field(
            "jsonb_pretty(array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(r)))::jsonb)", 
            JSONB.class
         ))
        .from(subquery.asTable("r"))
}
```

And now, you can execute any query in your desired form:

```java
JSONB result = ctx.fetchValue(json(select(T.A, T.B).from(T)));
```

#### Converting between PG arrays and JSON arrays

A note on performance. It seems that you're converting between data types a bit often. Specifically, I'd suggest you avoid aggregating a PostgreSQL array and turning that into a JSON array, but to use `JSONB_AGG()` directly. I haven't tested this, but it seems to me that the extra data structure seems unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed to get started. It should be noted that `forJSON` isn't available in the Open Source edition even if you use PostgreSQL. So plain SQL templating seems the way to go for my experiments. You are right likely right regarding unnecessary conversions, will optimize that later if I commit to this strategy.